# Android: Fragment is not receiving RESULT_OK in Activity result contract

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

I am using ActivityResultContract API in my fragment. Fragment A is in Activity A, from where Activity B is called which has Fragment B. Code in Fragment A is as follows:

```
 val makePaymentContract = registerForActivityResult(CustomContract()) { uri: Uri? ->
    Log.d("FragmentA", "DATA URI: ${uri.toString()}")
 }
```

This is custom contract:

```
class CustomContract : ActivityResultContract<DataHolder, Uri>() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: DataHolder?): Intent {
        val intent = Intent(context, ActivityB::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("data1", input?.data1)
        intent.putExtra("data2", input?.data2)
        intent.putExtra("data3", input?.data3)
        intent.putExtra("data4", input?.data4)
        return intent
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri? {
        Log.d("CustomContract", "Result Code $resultCode")
        when (resultCode) {
            Activity.RESULT_OK -> return intent?.data        // Return the data
            else -> return null
        }
    }
}
```

where `DataHolder` is a simple data class. Below code is in Fragment B(which is in Activity B)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("custom://thank_you?id=" + id + "&amt_paid=" + 
totalPaidAmt + "&order_type=" + orderType);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
requireActivity().finish();
```

The problem is FragmentA always receives null uri. Upon debugging, found out returned resultCode is always `RESULT_CANCELED`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Found out the mistake. I was not setting result from Fragment B

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("custom://thank_you?id=" + id + "&amt_paid=" + 
totalPaidAmt + "&order_type=" + orderType);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
requireActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
requireActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a clue to how to handle contracts in fragments